# list comprehension replace if condition else

Tags: python, list, replace, list-comprehension

I am trying to format a list with height values but some of the elements are not values

```
hei=['NN', '99.0m', '99.0m', '99.0m', '99.0m', '97.0m', '97.0m', '97.0m','rat_v2']
```

so i want to delete the 'm' with rstrip and replace the non numeric values for '_'

This was my try

```
heiFormat=[k.rstrip('m') if k[0].isdigit else k.replace(k,'_') for k in hei]
```

but the result is not totally correct as if does not replace the non numeric

```
heiFormat=['NN', '99.0', '99.0', '99.0', '99.0', '97.0', '97.0', '97.0','rat_v2']
```

while i want something like

```
heiFormat=['_', '99.0', '99.0', '99.0', '99.0', '97.0', '97.0', '97.0','_']
```

what is wrong or missing?

Answer (score 5):

When you do - `k[0].isdigit` - you are just accessing the function, you are not calling it, that is why that condition evaluates to true for all values.

You should call it. And you also do you not need the `replace` , a simpler way would be to directly put `'_'` there as `k.replace(k,'<something>')` is same as directly using `'<something>'`.

Example -

```
>>> heiFormat=[k.rstrip('m') if k[0].isdigit() else '_' for k in hei]
>>> heiFormat
['_', '99.0', '99.0', '99.0', '99.0', '97.0', '97.0', '97.0', '_']
```

Comment: Great it works. What it is not totally clear for me it is if with k[0].isdigit() i do not call the function and therefore all the values are true,....why does it work the else condition in your function??

Comment: You do not have the `()` , so you do not call the funciton, my version has that. `()` is the syntax for calling the function . Without it you are accessing the function object, not calling it.

Comment: @gis20: You perhaps need to know that absolutely any entity in Python can be successfully cast to type `bool`, which is what `if` does to its argument. The general rule is that null strings, empty lists and tuples and sets, zero numeric values and None are false (often referred to as "falsy"). Anything else, such as a function object, is "truthy".